# Resigning keyboard on touch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I've found some code that helps me resign the keyboard when a user touches the screen off of the UITextView element.

Here's how it looks:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if([self.speechBubble.speechText isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != self.speechBubble.speechText){
    [self.speechBubble.speechText resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This works perfectly so far, and will remove the keyboard if a user touches anywhere outside of the text view. However, it only works for the particular object that I'm running it for, so if I have two speechBubbles, it won't work.

How can I change this so that ANY speechBubble will have the same effect? (I could move this code from my ViewController to my SpeechBubble class, but I'd have a little issue with how to use [touch view] to get touches outside of the speechBubble's view. ) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something I just discovered recently that may be of use to you is:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

It will resign first responder from any element that currently has it without you having to manually keep track of it yourself.

In reference to your example code, something like this might work, depending on how your speechBubbles work:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  // Note the '!':
  if(![[touch view] class] isKindOfClass [speechBubble class]]){
    // It's not a bubble they touched, dismiss the keyboard:
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
  }
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, endEditing is great. I was thinking of trying to use isKindOfClass but didn't know you could access the [touch view] class like that. Thanks